# Can’t run MySQL query with an end of the year check

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I want to run MySQL query in end of the year. Query is OK. But I think PHP code is not work well. In Dreamweaver line number two displays an error. How can I fix this issue:

```
$gdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today'));
if($gdate==date("d-m-Y",strtotime('last day of december')){
    $queryrun=mysql_query( $query);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please show us the error message you are getting..

Comment: @csmckelvey it is indicate red mark near line 89 in dreamweawer

Comment: @Damith it is indicate red mark near line 89 in dreamweawer

Comment: @SasinduRHN When we ask for the error, we mean what is the error message, not what line it happened to appear on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$gdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today'));
if($gdate==date("Y-m-d",strtotime('last day of december'))){
    $queryrun=mysql_query( $query);
```

you were checking with `d-m-Y` which is wrong. both date format wasn't same and that the query is not running. and also a closing `)` bracket was missing.

Note: mysql_query will be deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code the answer is very obvious. Here is my test code:

```
$gdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today'));
$lastdate = date("d-m-Y",strtotime('last day of december'));

echo $gdate . '<br />';
echo $lastdate . '<br />';
```

The output for me is:

```
2014-01-01
31-12-2014
```

Because in one line you have `Y-m-d` and the other you have `d-m-Y`.

I would recommend doing it like this:

```
$date_format = "Y-m-d";
$gdate = date($date_format, strtotime('today'));
$lastdate = date($date_format,strtotime('last day of december'));
if ($gdate == $lastdate) {
  $queryrun=mysql_query( $query);
}
```

By setting `$date_format` in one place you can avoid getting confused by manually placing it in each check.

Comment: thanks it is work well. Wish you great Happy new Year

Answer (score 1):

### The cause of your error:

You have a bracket still open, count how many `(` you have, and how many `)` you have on the second line.

If you just add another closing bracket before the `{` you'll be fine.

i.e., (*note the 3 closing brackets on the second line*)

```
$gdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today'));    
if($gdate==date("d-m-Y",strtotime('last day of december'))){
    $queryrun=mysql_query( $query);
}
```

### Your next issue:

While the above will fix your syntax and allow the code to run, you'll still have issues because of your date formats.

Make sure that the date format that you are using is consistent.

Your `$gdate` is using a different format to what you're checking with in your `if` statement.

```
$gdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime('today'));    
if($gdate == date("d-m-Y",strtotime('last day of december'))){
    $queryrun = mysql_query( $query);
}
```

Comment: really... someone downvoted this? It points out the cause of the error which was the initial reason for the question being posted, then resolves the issue he's bound to have once syntax is fixed.

Comment: I will help you out! +1!

Comment: No problem, I hate erroneous downvotes with no explanations!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things. First, `date` doesn't have to be given a timestamp. If you omit that argument it just uses the current date. And `strtotime('today')` is a bad way to do that anyways. It's better to use `time()`, which doesn't have to do any parsing.

Second, you're reversing your arguments. You call `date("Y-m-d")` and then `date("d-m-Y")` and then compare them. They'll never match up because the order is different.

```
$gdate = date("Y-m-d");
if($gdate==date("Y-m-d", strtotime('last day of december')){
    $queryrun=mysql_query( $query);
}
```